# $.AJAX to $.POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Can someone help me to convert this code to $.post,Any code I replace is not functioning. Thank you

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://192.168.254.107/webs/main/ajax/validateLogin.php",
      data: sendData,
      success: function(data) {
          $("#info").html(data);
         var ReturnMessage = data;
         var mes = ReturnMessage.toString().trim();


         if (mes != "" && mes != "Invalid Login!") {
              localStorage.setItem("message", ReturnMessage);
              window.localStorage.setItem("username", username);
              window.localStorage.setItem("data", data);
              document.location.href = "trackme.html";

          } else {
              alert(mes);
          }

      }

  });
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you read this? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$.post('http://192.168.254.107/webs/main/ajax/validateLogin.php', sendData, function(data) {

    $("#info").html(data);
    var ReturnMessage = data;
    var mes = ReturnMessage.toString().trim();

    if (mes != "" && mes != "Invalid Login!") {
        localStorage.setItem("message", ReturnMessage);
        window.localStorage.setItem("username", username);
        window.localStorage.setItem("data", data);
        document.location.href = "trackme.html";

    } else {
        alert(mes);
    }

});
```

source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: In this case, is `sendData` an object?

Comment: Here's the code of sendData.   var sendData = {"username": username, "password" : password, "time" : time};

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$.post("http://192.168.254.107/webs/main/ajax/validateLogin.php", sendData).done(function(data) {
          $("#info").html(data);
         var ReturnMessage = data;
         var mes = ReturnMessage.toString().trim();


         if (mes != "" && mes != "Invalid Login!") {
              localStorage.setItem("message", ReturnMessage);
              window.localStorage.setItem("username", username);
              window.localStorage.setItem("data", data);
              document.location.href = "trackme.html";

          } else {
              alert(mes);
          }

      });
```